# SDRs synchronization

Tags: synchronization, software-defined-radio

I have 3 software defined radios (we can suppose that we have Ettus X310). I need to synchronize them because I need a high level of accuracy.

I know that I can use the Octoclock to synchronize them, but the problem is that the SDRs should be put at very long distances i.e. more than 100 meters from each other.

Do you have any suggestion about how to synchronize 3 or more software defined radios without using an Octoclock?

Comment: How accurately do you need to synchronize?  That will probably change the nature of the responses.  Can you add and order of magnitude that is acceptable to your question?

Comment: I'm afraid that if you want to synchronize (time and/or ref. freq) several USRPs X310 separated by 100m, you will need as many GPSDOs (essentially the Octoclock is a GPSDO with a 1:8 splitter).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. @GrapefruitIsAwesome I should reach an accuracy about of 1~1.5 meters max for localization purposes. For danipascual, probably yes, I need 3 GPSDOs (I cannot use an Octoclock).